# Running command-line script with generated database configuration

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm looking to run a script from the command line using the following command:

```
./cake updateSearchText main
```

"UpdateSearchTextShell.php" is a script that's in the Command folder and seems to work fine in other circumstances (see below). However, when I run this, I get a "The datasource configuration 'default' was not found in database.php" error.

Because the project in question is open source, I keep secrets like the database password in a separate file and load them in php. My database.php looks like this:

```
<?php
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
    var $default = null;

    function __construct () {
        $secrets = Configure::read('secrets');
        $this->default = $secrets['database'];
    }
}
?>
```

If I replace that with a simple definition of $default as an array specified in the first line of the class, the script runs with no errors. Clearly I can't leave it there in the repo, though, and I'd really rather not have to manually type it in every time I push new changes to the site.

Any thoughts on how to get the database.php above to work with command line scripts, or how to approach the issue of secrets in a way that won't confuse cake?

Comment: For starters, try running the script from the `app` folder, not from the `Console` folder. I remember that the CWD could cause problems when it's not pointing to the `app` folder.

Comment: I think that may have done it -- thanks! If you want to add that as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as the correct one.